# hackage-server fails to build - are there specific ghc/cabal version requirements?

Tags: haskell, cabal, hackage

I am trying to build and run a copy of the Hackage server https://github.com/haskell/hackage-server. I followed the instructions here https://github.com/haskell/hackage-server/wiki and also the instructions in the readme. Whichever I try, when trying to build with ghc 7.8.4 and cabal 1.22 I receive the following error:

```
Preprocessing executable 'hackage-server' for hackage-server-0.5.0...
Main.hs:40:8:
Could not find module ‘Network.URI’
It is a member of the hidden package ‘network-uri-2.6.0.1’.
Perhaps you need to add ‘network-uri’ to the build-depends in your .cabal file.
It is a member of the hidden package ‘network-2.4.2.3’.
Perhaps you need to add ‘network’ to the build-depends in your .cabal file.
```

I have also tried using the latest Haskell Platform, and I get the same failure message.

I'm trying to work out if this is a bug in the current master branch of hackage-server or if it is something to do with the way I installed ghc or cabal.

EDIT: I've tried again with the Ubuntu 14.04 repo haskell-platform (ghc 7.6.3, cabal 1.16) and the same error happens.

Comment: Does it work if you add `network-uri >= 2.6` and `network >= 2.6` to the `build-depends`?

Comment: @LambdaFairy That does clear that error, thank you! I figured from the compiler error that I might be able to fix it that way, but I didn't want to start fiddling with that until I was sure it wasn't related to the ghc version etc.

Comment: Great! I've posted that as an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`network-uri`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/network-uri) was [split from `network`](http://haskell.1045720.n5.nabble.com/Splitting-Network-URI-from-the-network-package-td5753966.html) a while ago, but it looks like Hackage hasn't been updated with that change.

As a workaround, open `hackage-server.cabal` and add these lines to `build-dependencies`:

```
network >= 2.6,
network-uri >= 2.6
```

That should get it working again.

Comment: Great, thanks. Just thought I'd add that hackage-server.cabal references network in multiple build-dependencies (for hackage-mirror, tests and so on) and all of these need to be changed.